# Why the variable becomes zero?

Tags: c, types, casting, ctype, typecasting-operator

Test is on Linux 32bit:

I found a bug in my C code and I simplify the code and put it here:

```
#define al *(char*)(eax_ptr)
int eax = 0;
int *eax_ptr = &eax;
int edx = 0;
char hh = 254;
.......

eax = hh;
edx = al;
```

The problem is that, edx should be 254 but where I use gdb to debug,
I fould edx equal zero.

Could anyone give me some help on this problem..?

Thank you!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: So what processor is this? Your variable names hint at x86, but I don't see how it can print zero unless it's big-endian.

Comment: @Mysticial x86 I use Macbook and run Linux virtual machine in it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Great, I change #define al *(char*)(eax_ptr) to #define al *(char*)(eax_ptr+16) and it works! Thank you!

Comment: What ever it is you are doing, it doesn't repro here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ea0b63fd9c78c52 Macs use x86 which is little-endian. Unless your virtual machine is somehow big-endian.

Comment: I presume `dex` is a typo for `edx`. Your question would be improved by providing a [complete self-contained executable program](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: `#define al (char)(eax_ptr+16)`? First, I think you mean `char*`, not `char`. Second, `eax_ptr+16` points 16 `int`s (probably 64 bytes) past the address of `eax`; if it works, it's coincidental.

Comment: @KeithThompson Hi Keith, I use #define al *(char*)(eax_ptr), and secondly, my code is running on 32 bit linux...so I don't think it is coincidental.

Comment: @computereasy: The markdown formatting is messing you up; your asterisks are being interpreted as italics. Enclose any source code in a comment in backticks. I think you're saying you use `#define al *(char*)(eax_ptr)`. But in your comment from 3 hours ago, you did something with `eax_ptr+16`, and that makes no sense; it refers to a memory location that's probably 64 bytes past the address of `eax`. Again, if you'll update your question to show a *complete* and *compilable* program that exhibits the problem, it would be very helpful, both to you and to future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of this code is not predictable. The initialization

`char hh = 254;`

Is not assured to be successful on every platform. `char` may not be able to hold 254 (and it is not if your platform uses signed chars and 8 bit characters, a common choice).

Assuming that a `char` *can* hold a value such as 254, this assignment:

`eax = hh;`

Will expand `hh` to the size of an integer by inserting leading zeros. When you later interpret `eax` (an integer) as if it were a char (which is really what you're doing with the cast), the result will depend on your machine's endianness: if it's little endian, it will read 254, otherwise, it will read 0.